# Saving metadata for asset when uploading file

Tags: assets, hook

I'm trying to set the value of a custom field for an asset while uploading the asset. But somehow the value is not being saved. I can see the data in the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` and `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` hook, it is also in the dirty fields array, but it's just not saved in the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
Event::on(
    Asset::class,
    Asset::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_FILE,
    function (AssetEvent $event) {
        if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest()) {
            $asset = $event->asset;
            if ($asset->extension === 'mp3' && $asset->tempFilePath) {
                $mp3 = new Mp3($asset->tempFilePath);
                $duration = $mp3->getDuration();
                $asset->setFieldValue('duration', $duration);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to resave the element after using `setFieldValue`. Maybe try hooking into `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` instead?

```php
Event::on(
    Asset::class,
    Asset::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function (AssetEvent $event) {
        $asset = $event->asset;
        //Avoid endless loop if the asset already has duration set
        if ($asset->extension == 'mp3' && !$asset->duration) {
            $mp3 = new Mp3($asset->path);
            $duration = $mp3->getDuration();
            $asset->setFieldValue('duration', $duration);
            Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);
        }
        
    }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The asset is in S3, so I don't want to download it again. It has to happen before uploading it to S3. I am also getting the following errors: `Argument #1 ($event) must be of type craft\events\AssetEvent, craft\events\ModelEvent given` and `Invalid field handle: duration` (the duration field does exist though!) I did workaround those errors, and can see the duration is in the dirty fields array and the saveElement function is being called, but it's just not being saved!

Comment: @thomasjonas - Looking at the [EVENT_AFTER_SAVE docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-base-element.html#event-after-save), it's returning a `ModelEvent` instead of an `AssetEvent`. 

So changing...

`function (AssetEvent $event) {` 

...to ... 

`function (ModelEvent $event) {`

... should fix this error.